# where is the actual string of these two environment variable (a) environ b) envp) stored?

Tags: c, linux, process, operating-system

I know at runtime, `environ` is a global pointer variable which ended up stored in the data section. `envp` is a local variable defined in the main, so it stores in the stack or top of the stack. Correct me if I am wrong.

But the question is, where is the actual string information these two environment stored? Both in the stack?

I attach the two code segments that these two environment variables are used.
for `environ`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
extern char **environ; 
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ char **env_variable_ptr;
  env_variable_ptr = environ;
  while (*env_variable_ptr != NULL)
  { printf("%s\n", *env_variable_ptr);
    env_variable_ptr++;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

For `envp`:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp){
    while(*envp != NULL){ 
    printf("%s\n", *envp);
    envp++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: C does not specify - implementation specific.  (I do not even think Linux specifies -maybe it does.) Why is their location important?

Comment: It's stored somewhere in memory where your process has read access. Why do you care?

Comment: Empirically, the environment strings are normally stored just after the argument strings. The sum of the lengths of the arguments and environment is limited by `ARG_MAX`. They're provided by the alternative program startup recognized (but nor mandated) by the C standard ([Annex J.5.1 Environment arguments](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.5.1)), so it makes sense that they're stored close together. But nothing specifies where they're stored — just that they _are_ stored and made available to the program. There isn't necessarily a global variable pointing at the command-line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Check your specific compiler's documentation.

The language definition does not specify where they get stored, only how that storage should behave:

> **5.1.2.2.1 Program startup**
> ...
> 2     If they are declared, the parameters to the `main` function shall obey the following
> constraints:
> ...
>        —The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall
> be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program
> startup and program termination.

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

The standard does not define `envp`, but it's logical to assume any implementation that does would treat it the same as `argv`.

Comment: I wouldn't be so confident of finding details in compiler documentation, as I don't expect this to be compiler-specific, or even language-specific (in the sense that every executable has a runtime-accessible environment).

Answer (score 0):

The argument vector, environment strings, and some extra information (the "auxiliary vector" on ELF-based systems) are *usually* placed above the bottom of the initial thread's stack.  This location is used because the operating system has to create a read-write address range for the stack and write stuff to it, during process startup, *anyway*, so it may as well put all of the data that varies from invocation to invocation there.

This *may* be specified in the "processor-specific application binary interface" (psABI) document for your CPU and operating system.  For instance, see the "process initialization" section of the [x86-64/ELF psABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-1.0.pdf), used on most x86-64-based operating systems (with the prominent exception of Windows), particularly page 32 where it talks about the "information block."

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the *data* that forms the program's environment, along with the data that forms the program's arguments, is stored at the top of the program's address space, above the initial stack.

Pointers to the individual values -- both for environment and arguments -- are placed *on* the stack.

Because these locations are so close together (on Linux), you'll often see statements like "the environment data is placed on the stack". That's only partly true.